# Moment JS fromnow() outputting shorthand

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I receive a UTC datetime from the server, and am attempting to display it in readable form:

```
moment.utc(utc_date).local().fromNow();
```

In my local development environment (Homestead, Laravel) this works, and will display exactly as required, eg:

```
a day ago
```

or

```
4 hours ago
```

But on my production server it is outputting what seems like shorthand:

```
1d
```

or

```
4h
```

I cant seem to figure this out and my searches have yielded nothing. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: I'd assume that either you don't have [locales](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/master/locale) on your production server or you're testing with a locale that is not yet present and therefore it's falling back to d/h.
This is probably a bad assumption since there's a fallback `defaultRelativeTime` in the code but TBH you really just gotta step through your code in a debugger in production yourself. It shouldn't be hard to figure out where it fails. (By the way - I begin to hate es6 modules... so many files just stop it - this is overkill *moment*)

Comment: What type of value is actually in the `utc_date` variable?  Is it a `Date` object? a number? a string?  Give an example please.  Also, in general, `fromNow` is not going to care if you switched to utc mode or local mode because "now" is utc-based internally anyway.

Comment: @MattJohnson IMHO it's a detail that we shouldn't focus on as you already stated yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the kind of output you described, you would have had to customize the locale settings.  Moment doesn't have a locale with this format built in.

Others have asked for it, and there's an example of how to do it in [moment issue #2781](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2781).  Perhaps one of the libraries you use is taking this approach.

There's nothing that is machine-specific that would change the result you're getting, so if you say it's different on your production server, then I'd speculate there is either different code in that environment, or it is exercising a different code path.

If you need to explicitly clear the customizations to a locale, you can revert it like so:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', null);
```

Comment: Loading Moment via npm should mean it loads all locales automatically right? Moment is recognising the locale as 'en', and after a lot of refreshing and testing, it appears to display correctly ~10% of the time, and displays as shorthand the rest of the time.

Comment: See [Loading locales in NodeJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/).

Comment: Probably some other library in your chain is modifying the `en` locale globally.